# MediaWiki "open_basedir restriction in effect"

Tags: php, mediawiki, open-basedir

I installed a local MediaWiki and gave it access to the following directories in `php.ini`:

```
open_basedir = /srv/http/:/home/:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/:/usr/share/webapps/mediawiki
```

Why do I still get the following message? It doesn't make sense to me:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/images/lock_yBgMBwiR) is not within the allowed path(s): (/srv/http/:/home/:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/:/usr/share/webapps/mediawiki) in <b>/usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/includes/GlobalFunctions.php</b> on line <b>1196</b><br />
```

How can `/usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/images/lock_yBgMBwiR` not be within `/usr/share/webapps/mediawiki`?

I don't have further restrictions in httpd.conf (I've read in the official php documentation that file open_basedir statements can be too).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/images/lock_yBgMBwiR is symlink folder, check with ls -l.

Comment: You can try `realpath /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/images/lock_yBgMBwiR` to see what it actually resolves to.

Comment: `$ realpath /usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/images/lock_yBgMBwiR` gave me `/var/lib/mediawiki/lock_yBgMBwiR`. Thanks!

Comment: yup realpath more specified.